# How to pass an extra argument to shared component in angular,so it uses different API

Tags: angular

learning angular,my question is simple,i have shared modal component,so it opens in two different places in app,
I need it to have different api triggered ,based on which button i use to access modal component,so basically this is one of 2 buttons that opens the modal component

```
<button mat-stroked-button type="button" class="bulk-icon-button" [hidden]="selectedRows.length !== 1" (click)="openModal()">
   <span fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start center" fxLayoutGap="8px">
     <mat-icon class="material-icons">insert_drive_file</mat-icon>
   <span class="text">Open modal</span>
   </span>
</button>
```

Comment: Could you please share the implementation of your `openModal()` method and also share the implementation of your `ModalService`?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass in the observable returned by the http client, and subscribe to it inside of your modal.